# How many collators are selected at a time or we can say same block height to authorise a parachain block?

Tags: polkadot, parachain, parachain-collator, cumulus

"I'm trying to understand the mechanics of parachain block authorization in blockchain networks like Polkadot and similar multi-chain systems. Specifically, I'd like to know:

1. How many collators are typically selected at a time to authorize a parachain block?
2. Is there a selection process for these collators?
3. How many collators can collate at the same block height ?

I'm interested in the selection process for collators and how many of them are typically involved in producing a parachain block. Any insights, references, or resources on this topic would be greatly appreciated."

Answer (score 0):

Because BABE does not function effectively for parachains, I presume that you are utilizing AURA.

AURA generates blocks sequentially, with each collator being assigned a slot one after another. If Collator A is absent (offline or otherwise), Collator B will assume A's slot.

```
A -> B -> C -> D -> A -> ..

# in case of B being offline

A -> C -> D -> A -> ..
```

If you are interested in block production, I recommend reading the AURA/BABE documentation first.

Comment: Does this imply that only a single collator, chosen from among all collators, is responsible for creating a block, and subsequently, only one parachain block generated by that collator is transmitted to the relay validators, establishing a direct connection between the relay chain validators and that specific collator?

Comment: Each slot belongs to only one collator.